# Logitech H390 USB headset not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, sound, logitech, headset

Today, I bought a Logitech H390 USB headset and it doesn't appear in my sound settings. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First, after you plug the headset in, give us the output of 

    dmesg |tail

Second, restart the computer *with the headset plugged in* and let us know if it's detected.

Comment: Here is the result for  dmesg |tail https://ghostbin.com/paste/htdtf
Restarting the computer did help, however if I unplug the headset and plug it back in, I have to restart again

Comment: Hi @pgrytdal . Could you solve this?